# Drupal webforms - How can you enable reseting of drafts

Tags: forms, drupal

There is an option you can enable for users to save their drafts, but doesn't seem to be an option to let them clear it. Surely this should be possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a markup field at the bottom of my webform containing:

```
<a href="node/50/submissions">Manage previous submissions or drafts</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify if you want Drupal 6 or Drupal 7 support, but at least in Drupal 6 there is a module for that: [Revision Deletion](http://drupal.org/project/revision_deletion)

It doesn't look like it has been ported to D7 yet and, though there is a "issue" for it discussing alternatives on D7, it looks like you might be stuck if you need this feature on Drupal 7. Granting the permissions to normal users to "Delete revisions" is far too dangerous. But it really shouldn't be such a hard project to port to Drupal 7.

Comment: I couldn't see how to get this to work how I wanted it.
What I did was put a markup field at the bottom of the form linking to the submissions so people can "manage" their submissions and drafts that way.